# Create a python dictionary of lists

Tags: python, django

I am new to python and django and was wondering how I would go about making a dict of lists.

My 4 lists are;

```
ap = request.POST.getlist('amount_paid[]')
pd = request.POST.getlist('paid_date[]')
method = request.POST.getlist('method[]')
comments = request.POST.getlist('comments[]')
```

How would I make that into a dictionary I could then loop over in a django template such as;

```
{% for i in the_dict %}
{{i.amount_paid}}
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks in advance!

Update:

hmm I not sure I posted my question properly. In php, I can do the following on an array of fields:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['amount_paid']);$i++) {
echo $_POST['amount_paid'][$i];
echo $_POST['paid_date'][$i];
}
```

All the form fields are input text fields.. How would I do this in Django?

Comment: Please don't use field names ending in `[]`. That's a PHP-ism and has no place in Django.

Comment: @Daniel [] is jqueryism now. Its sad but true. I remember reading the reason for this decision somewhere. Don't remember though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's [`dict`](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/stdtypes.html#dict) syntax is very simple. It's just key-value pairs inside a pair of curly braces, like this:

```
the_dict = {
    'amount_paid': request.POST.getlist('amount_paid[]'),
    'paid_date': request.POST.getlist('paid_date[]'),
    'method': request.POST.getlist('method[]'),
    'comments': request.POST.getlist('comments[]'),
}
```

Following your update, it looks like you don't want a `dict` at all but [`zip()`](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/functions.html#zip):

```
post = request.POST
lists = zip(post.getlist('amount_paid[]'), 
        post.getlist('paid_date[]'),
        post.getlist('method[]'),
        post.getlist('comments[]'),
        )
for amount_paid, paid_date, method, comments in lists:
    print amount_paid
    print paid_date
    # et cetera...
```

Comment: Can you please update your question with the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: N.B: This is how I would do it in straight Python. I'm not a Django programmer.

Answer (score 1):

You could create:

```
the_dict = dict(amount_paid=ap, paid_date=pd, method=method, comments=comments)
```

Also your template code does not make sense. You are iterating over the keys of the dict and not using them in the body.

EDIT

```
{% for key in the_dict %}
    {% for val in the_dict[key] %}
        <input name="{{key}}" value="{{val}}"/>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Or directly from the source: `the_dict = dict((param, request.POST.getlist('%s[]'%param)) for param in ('amount_paid', 'paid_date', 'method', 'comments'))`

Comment: @eumiro. You again... And I concede. Your method is sweeter. :)

Answer (score 1):

As often happens, you're not really asking about the problem you actually need to solve: you've done things in a certain (wrong) way, and are asking about how to get yourself out of the problem you've got yourself into.

If I understand you correctly, you've got a set of fields - amount_paid, paid_date, method, comments - and each field appears multiple times on the form, so you've got one set of values for each entry. You're presumably trying to sort these into a list of dicts for each row.

Well, this is not the right way to go about it in Django. You should be using [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/formsets/), which give you one form for each row in a table - ie, exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: kind of, however I am adding and removing rows dynamically using jquery.. it's not a static form - wouldn't it be just as effective to code it manually? Please correct me if I'm wrong tho like I said i'm new to django.

Comment: No, this is still the use-case of formsets - your jQuery should just add a row with the relevant prefix, and increase the hidden form count fields.